# Selenium running from an ASP.NET application

Tags: asp.net, selenium

I have an ASP.net application with selenium code inside.

I want that when the user clicks on a button at the client side, the browser will open on the server side which is running Windows Server 2012.

The problem is, that when I try to do this I get "unable to bind to locking port 7054" error message on the server.

I can feel there is a problem with my approach to the whole thing,
The question is, what's the correct approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I found out that I need to use a Selenium Grid server from here: http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/

And then followed the following article: 
https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/Grid2

use "java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.14.0.jar" in command line in order to start the server.

And then in code:

```
DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), capability);
```